# Aws On demand Pricing for Ec2 instances that are downsized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have downsized on-demand ec2 instances using memory& cpu utilization paramters(average and peak). When will the actual pricing start getting reduced or show up in the Billing.

WE have downsized ec2 on - demand instances. Expecting that prices to be halved approximately.

Comment: The cost change will take effect immediately. Billing page may trail 24hrs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. @jordannm i have a query regarding the same issue that i asked above. If these are part of Compute savings plan committed per hour would we still get the benefit that you stated above even after we change the instance

Answer (score 2):

Depending on instance type, you either pay by the hour, or by the second.
So you worst case scenario, you will pay for an extra hour of the upscaled instances. But then you will pay the price of the down scaled ones.

> With On-Demand instances, you pay for compute capacity by the hour or the second depending on which instances you run. No longer-term commitments or upfront payments are needed. You can increase or decrease your compute capacity depending on the demands of your application and only pay the specified per hourly rates for the instance you use.

Source : https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

But the billing view will only update every 24 hours or so. So you won't see your new billing right away. You can check that after one, or a few days.

> The current month's data is available for viewing in about 24 hours. The rest of your data takes a few days longer. Cost Explorer updates your cost data at least once every 24 hours.

Source : https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the update. That was quick and prompt. We have raised our query with aws support however they have not responded yet.

Comment: I have a query regarding the same issue that i asked above. If these are part of Compute savings plan committed per hour would we still get the benefit that you stated above even after we change the instance type.

Comment: Yes. Saving plans apply regardless of instance type, size, or region. This is no true for Reserved instances though. Those are very specific to instance types and to regions. They are less flexible. I personally tend to stick to saving plans when possible, to saving plans, as they are more forgiving and are applied on wider range of services. They even work for Fargate, lambda functions, and across accounts that belong to the same organization

Comment: Thank you for promptly answering all my queries. Hey, this is the faster way to get answers than AWS support.